# Question regarding Voltage-controlled resistors in PSPICE

Tags: spice, pspice

I am quite new to PSPICE, and I am using Capture to design my circuit. To explain what I am trying to do, I have two circuits that I want to connect via a voltage in the following manner:

In circuit 1 I have a certain voltage, let us call it V1.

In circuit 2 I have a resistor (R1), with a value that I want to be dependent on V1. So that basically, R1 = f(V1), where f is a function. The function, f, is not necessarily linear.

Is there any easy way to do this in SPICE/PSPICE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, there is a way to do this in pspice:

[image]

Or this way:

```
.SUBCKT RES_10K 1 2
ERES   1  3  VALUE = { I(VSENSE)*10K }
VSENSE 3  2  DC 0
.ENDS
```

Sources: [E circuit center](http://www.ecircuitcenter.com/Circuits/vc_resistor1/vc_resistor1.htm)

Just a side note, this and other functions are accomplished [much easier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/349861/changing-parameter-values-from-a-value-list-file-in-spice/350217#350217) in [LT spice](http://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html), the package is free and I believe the solver is better and it's easier to use and accomplish special functions like this

Comment: +1 for the LTspice reference. Some time ago I went to a friend and tried to use OrCad, the last time was in college. I found it very clunky compared to LTspice. Of course, it's just an opinion.

Comment: It is difficult to use, and much more difficult when you want to do custom functions, you can simulate almost anything with B-sources including ADC's

Comment: I am quite new, so I am not able to implement the circuit above using OrCAD capture. The problem is setting the value of ERES to { I(VSENSE)*10k }, how do I do that. I have tried to double right click on the voltage value of ERES and write the expression, but that does not work.

Comment: Its been a while, but I believe this is done through the property editor. http://www.pspice.com/how-define-model-parameter-so-it-visible-schematic-and-easily-editable-schematic